# Querying a collection within an entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I currently have a simple one to many relationship between products and multiple deals (a table of 1 million deals in total) associated with the products.

What I'm trying to do is loop through the top 10 products and select the top deals relating to the product.

What would be the best way to achieve this in Doctrine 2? I was contemplating adding a method such as getTopDeals within the product entity, and then calling it within twig as I looped through each product like so:

```
{% for product in popular_products %}
    {% set deal = product.getTopDeal() %}
    {{ product.title }} - {{ deal.title }}, {{deal.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I've read that generally it is frowned upon adding methods such as this into models, so I'm at an end as to what the best way to do this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is, "fat models, thin controllers". The logic for selecting the top deals for a product definitely has a place on the model, if the model itself is capable of doing this filtering, eg. it only needs the deal objects, which it has a relation with. For this, you could use the [Criteria API](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections), something like:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
class Product {
    private $deals; // many-to-many to Products

    public function getTopDeals() {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()->orderBy(array('price', 'DESC'))->setMaxResults(10);
        return $this->deals->matching($criteria);
    }
}
```

If the selection logic is more complicated, and needs to reach into the entity manager, then it is better suited for placing on an EntityRepository.

Comment: I do like this solution. If I only wanted it to return a single deal as an object how would I go about doing that? setMaxResults(1) still returns an array collection.

Comment: The Criteria API does not have a method currently for selecting only a single entity, you will have to do it manually.

Comment: Alright. In the end I did setMaxResults(1) and then deals->matching($criteria)->getFirst() which seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Make a method in your Deals repository to accept a parameter and return the topdeal.  In your controller, array_map() your products to produce an array of deals keyed by product.  Then pass the deals array along with your products array to your template.

edit: sample requested:

Repository:

```
public function getTopDealProduct($productid)
{
    $em=$this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Deal')->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb->join('d.product', 'p');
    $qb->setMaxResults(1);
    $qb->addOrderBy('d.price');
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function s2JUsorAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $dealrep = $this->em->getRepository('Bundle:Deal');
    $prodrep = $this->em->getRepository('Bundle:Product');
    $products= $prodrep->getProducts();  // Not shown here, write this
    $deals= array_map(function($element) use ($dealrep){
         return $dealrep->getTopDealProduct($element->getId());
    }
    ,$products);


    return $this->render('Bundle:Product:Deal.html.twig', array(
        'products'  => $products
       ,'deals'     => $deals
    ));
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an interesting solution, I don't suppose you could provide a brief example as I'm having difficulty understanding how you would use array_map in this instance.